# When I use StringBuilder.Append instead of .AppendLine, do I need to add additional .Append(crlf)s?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, append, stringbuilder

I'm adapting some code I found here: http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/03/sending-raw-epl2-directly-to-a-zebra-lp2844-via-c/#comment-1636, but in VS 2003 / .NET 1.1, StringBuilder's AppendLine method is not recognized, so I truncated it to .Append.

Will I need now to add #13#10 or so after each call to Append - I'm assuming that is something AppendLine does automatically.

Comment: Yes (some more characters so I can post this a comment)

Comment: And you can use Environment.NewLine

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

`AppendLine()` will append its argument, followed by `Environment.Newline`.
If you don't call `AppendLine()`, you will need to include the newline yourself.

Comment: I'm wondering if "\r\n" would be safer for this project (CE/CF) than Environment.Newline (which I would normally prefer).

Comment: Does it append a `\r\n` does it use `Environment.NewLine`?

Comment: @ClayShannon: You're right; I should have said `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: Environment.Newline also doesn't seem to be recognized in .NET 1.1

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Be wary of thinking of it as a CRLF though - [internally StringBuilder uses Environment.Newline](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Text/StringBuilder@cs/1305376/StringBuilder@cs) so it's worth using Environment.NewLine yourself for cross compatibility.

```
 [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(false)]
    public StringBuilder AppendLine() {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<stringbuilder>() != null);
        return Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(false)]
    public StringBuilder AppendLine(string value) {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<stringbuilder>() != null);
        Append(value);
        return Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

Edit: Unless you have a specific need to use CRLF because of hardware, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Decompiled source for `StringBuilder.AppendLine`

```
/// <summary>
/// Appends the default line terminator to the end of the current <see cref="T:System.Text.StringBuilder"/> object.
/// 
/// </summary>
/// 
/// <returns>
/// A reference to this instance after the append operation has completed.
/// 
/// </returns>
/// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException">Enlarging the value of this instance would exceed <see cref="P:System.Text.StringBuilder.MaxCapacity"/>.
///                 </exception><filterpriority>1</filterpriority>
[ComVisible(false)]
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public StringBuilder AppendLine()
{
  return this.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this @Dustin Kingen!